# Increase time for search in a select element HTML

Tags: javascript, html, user-experience

Anyone of you knows if there is a way to increase the time before that a search starting when the user is trying to select an element from a *select list* by typing the name of the element, in HTML.

- For example: I have a list of 100 elements, and the user wants to find the element "Adam Smith" but he is very slow and he can not type very fast in order to select the element Adam smith. Do you know if there is a way to help the user in this use case.

I can use a different component instead of the normal select in HTML, but I am working with a legacy system and I cannot change the source code too much. Anyway also JS solutions are well accepted

Comment: It seems that there is already a `timeout` timer connected to the search event while typing, you can override this, but that may be tricky, because the legacy script may persist, but highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is a perfect *use case* for the **debounce** method of [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce).

Here is a little example where the time the function will wait until fire is `500`:

```js
function doSearch () {
  $('#output').html('searched: ' + $('#search').val())
}

$('#search').on('input', _.debounce(doSearch, 500));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type=text id=search />
<p id=output></p>
```

```
function doSearch () {
  console.log('do search')
}

$('#search').on('input', _.debounce(doSearch, 500));
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for

Comment: Great. Lodash have pretty useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

To debug and find which functions are called when a user starts typing, you can add some JavaScript at the very end on the HTML output that adds (or overrides) the original behavior.

This may help tracking down the problem and find out where that timer value is set:

```
document.getElementById('thatInputElement').onKeyUp = function(event)
{
    console.log(event);
};
```

You can also achieve this directly from the dev-tools web-console in your browser, without tampering with the source-code.